# Crash "at <unknown> <0xffffffff>" when calling C# method from C which returns a value

Tags: c#, c, unity-game-engine, interop

I'm writing a native library in Go and C (thin wrapper) and interop code in C#.

I can successfully register C# methods as callbacks with the library and then call them from C when they don't return values. But I get a crash whenever I try to call callbacks which return values.

The library is compiled as a Windows DLL and here is the stack trace produced when I attempt to call a C# function in a Unity game:

```
=================================================================
    Native Crash Reporting
=================================================================
Got a UNKNOWN while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================

=================================================================
    Managed Stacktrace:
=================================================================
      at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
      at MyLib.Interop:TestCallGetIntCb <0x000cd>
      at MyLib.Test:TestCallGetIntCb <0x0007a>
      at Multiplayer:Update <0x000ea>
      at System.Object:runtime_invoke_void__this__ <0x00187>
=================================================================
```

Commenting out the callback call in the C code removes the error.

**Here is the code which produces the crash:**

**Native library:**

`callback.h`

```
typedef int (*GetIntCallback)();

void SubscribeGetIntCallback(GetIntCallback cb);
int GetInt();
```

`callback.c`

```
static GetIntCallback testGetIntCallback = 0;

void SubscribeGetIntCallback(GetIntCallback cb)
{
    testGetIntCallback = cb;
}

int GetInt()
{
    if (testGetIntCallback != 0)
    {
        return testGetIntCallback();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**C# Code:**

`Interop.cs`

```
public class Interop
{
    // Other code removed for clarity...

    public delegate int GetIntCallback();

    [DllImport("mylibrary")]
    public static extern void SubscribeGetIntCallback(GetIntCallback intCb);
}
```

`Test.cs`

```
public class Test
{
    // Other code removed for clarity...

    public Test()
    {
        Interop.SubscribeGetIntCallback(TestIntCb);
    }

    [MonoPInvokeCallback(typeof(Interop.GetIntCallback))]
    private int TestIntCb()
    {
        return 100;
    }
}
```

**For reference the code below works and does not crash:**

**Native library:**

`callback.h`

```
typedef void (*StringCallback)(const char *message, int size);

void SubscribeLogInfo(StringCallback cb);
void LogInfo(const char *message);
```

`callback.c`

```
static StringCallback logInfoCallback = 0;

void SubscribeLogInfo(StringCallback cb)
{
    logInfoCallback = cb;
}

void LogInfo(const char *message)
{
    if (logInfoCallback != 0)
    {
        logInfoCallback(message, (int)strlen(message));
    }
}
```

**C# code:**

`Interop.cs`

```
public class Interop
{
    // Other code removed for clarity...

    public delegate void StringCallback(IntPtr ptr, int size);

    [DllImport("mylibrary")]
    public static extern void SubscribeLogInfo(StringCallback cb);
}
```

`Events.cs`

```
public static class Events
{
    // Other code removed for clarity...

    public delegate void MessageEventHandler(object sender, MessageEventArgs args);
    public static event MessageEventHandler LogInfoEvent;

    static Events()
    {
        Interop.SubscribeLogInfo(OnLogInfo);
    }

    [MonoPInvokeCallback(typeof(Interop.StringCallback))]
    private static void OnLogInfo(IntPtr messagePtr, int size)
    {
        string message = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(messagePtr, size);
        LogInfoEvent?.Invoke(typeof(Events), new MessageEventArgs(message));
    }
}
```

Why do I get the crash when calling the method which returns an int, but not when I call the method which returns void?

My ideas:

- Is there a problem with my method signature?
- Is it because my Test class is not static?
- Is it because my TestIntCb() method is not static?
- Is it because the return value of TestIntCb() is in managed memory and not copied to unmanaged memory when it returns?
- Is there a type compatibility problem? int's are blittable aren't they, shouldn't it be copied with no conversion?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: `typedef int (*GetIntCallback)();` does not specify a function pointer to a function that takes no arguments - it specifies a pointer to a function that takes an indeterminate number of arguments.  You probably want `typedef int (*GetIntCallback)(void);` to provide a full function pointer type for a function that takes no arguments.  Similarly, `int GetInt();` should both be declared and defined as `int GetInt(void);`

Comment: Where is `GetIntCb` shown?

Comment: You don't specify calling conventions - they are often the cause of unexpected P/Invoke errors. This (the PInvokeStackImbalance MDA) is often handy https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/pinvokestackimbalance-mda

Comment: @AndrewHenle Ah yes, thank you. I had forgotten about this aspect of C. I have corrected it in the code.

Comment: @Practising Whoops, yep typo there, it was late at night when I constructed this question. Thanks, I've edited the question.

Comment: @Flydog57 Yes, thanks. Charlieface mentioned this in is answer too. I need to do a bit more reading into this to understand how they affect the methods calls, as it (appears that it) works without them. If you have a good resource for this I would appreciate a link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two issues I can see here:

- Missing calling convention both on the `DllImport` and on the delegat declaration, which I guess should be `CDecl`.
- You need to ensure the delegate object doesn't get disposed/collected too early. In most cases the easiest way to do this is by caching it in a field. Note that the field itself (or rather its containing object) must *also* not be collected, but you don't show how you are using that.

```cs
public class Interop
{
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public delegate int GetIntCallback();

    [DllImport("mylibrary", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.CDecl)]
    public static extern void SubscribeGetIntCallback(GetIntCallback intCb);
}

public class Test
{
    GetIntCallback _callback = TestIntCb;

    public Test()
    {
        Interop.SubscribeGetIntCallback(_callback);
    }

    [MonoPInvokeCallback(typeof(Interop.GetIntCallback))]
    private int TestIntCb()
    {
        return 100;
    }
}
```

---

On the same basis, the `string` version could also do with changes.

I note that you have put the event subscriber in the static constructor. This is probably a bad idea, put it into a separate function instead. Static events are also a bit of a bad idea, they need careful management to ensure you don't get a memory leak.

```cs
public class Interop
{
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public delegate void StringCallback(string str, int size);

    [DllImport("mylibrary", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern void SubscribeLogInfo(StringCallback cb);
}

public static class Events
{
    public delegate void MessageEventHandler(object sender, MessageEventArgs args);

    public static event MessageEventHandler LogInfoEvent;

    private StringCallback _callback = OnLogInfo;

    static Events()
    {
        Interop.SubscribeLogInfo(_callback);
    }

    [MonoPInvokeCallback(typeof(Interop.StringCallback))]
    private static void OnLogInfo(string message, int size)
    {
        LogInfoEvent?.Invoke(typeof(Events), new MessageEventArgs(message));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, the issue was resolved by caching a reference to the delegate function in a field. I find that the code works with or without the CallingConvention options in the attribute. Is there a good resource which describes when these calling conventions are required and how they are used? I have read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.callingconvention?view=net-7.0 and the table indicates that the calling convention dictates how the method is managed on the stack, but it doesn't say when each is appropriate.

Comment: Regarding your update with advice for the StringCallback code (thanks btw), I was to-ing and fro-ing over whether to use a singleton or static class for the events, and because the event class should exist for the life of the program and I expect only one or two classes to subscribe to the events, it shouldn't be difficult to manage. I understand that each subscriber MUST unsubscribe otherwise they won't be garbage collected.

Comment: Also, the `UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)` is very useful for automatically marshalling the string! I've switched over to that too.

Comment: To be honest I suspect the reason you didn't see an issue with the calling convention is that CDecl and StdCall are the same if you have no parameters. See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040108-00/?p=41163 a good description. Generally C and C++ would use CDecl, whereas Win32/WinApi functions would use StdCall.